# java Gui into Intellij

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, intellij-idea, netbeans

I developed a GUI form in Netbeans, and now I want to switch to IntelliJ. When I pull the forms from GitHub and try to view the form, it says:

"Form file is invalid: Not IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer form file"

Is there a way to convert them so I do not have to redesign the forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following commands in IntelliJ:

**File** -> **New** -> **Project from Existing Sources**

When the Import Project wizard opens, select **Create Project from Existing Sources**

Open the project you originally built in NetBeans.

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: I was successfully able to import the project that wasnt a problem but in netbeans the gui were in .form which i had to convert in .jfd to run it in Intellij. so i downloaded a plugin called JFormDesigner which converts the .form into .jfd and that works!
Appreciate your help, thanks!Q